# Enabling Angular JS in ONSEN pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I have just started messing around with Onsen UI and Angular JS.

I'm accessing a dessert.html, text/ons-template, via an ons-button, but the binded ng-model itemName is not being interpreted correctly.

I'm sure I'm missing something on connecting Angular with OnsenUI. Any tips on what I'm missing here ?

index.html

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
<ons-button modifier="large--quiet" onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('dessert.html', { animation : 'slide' } )">Dessert</ons-button>
</ons-list-item>

<script type="text/ons-template" id="dessert.html">
<ons-page>
<ons-toolbar>
<div class="center">Dessert</div>
</ons-toolbar>
<ons-list-item class="assgn-list" ng-controller="itemNameCtrl" ng-model="itemName">
{{itemName}}
</ons-list-item>
</ons-page>
</script>
```

js/app.js

```
var myApp;

(function()
{
    myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);
}
)();

 myApp.controller('itemNameCtrl', function($scope)
                  {
                  $scope.itemName = "Tiramisu";
                  $scope.$apply();
                  });
```

Comment: When you say "not being interpreted correctly.", you mean the "{{itemName}}" is still be shown instead of the interpolated value? I don't see a `ng-app="myApp"` line anywhere. Did you bootstrap your app?

Comment: precisely, {{itemName}} is still being shown. The ng-app="myApp" is in the html section, but I have also tried to declare it in the ons-list-item tag with no luck? Re: bootstrap, should I call ons.bootstrap() somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DW5FK7YnRHn9RvbajfJ7?p=preview) using your codebase and it's working. Give it a try. I added a back button for my convenience.

```
<script type="text/ons-template" id="dessert.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar><div class="center">Dessert</div></ons-toolbar>
      <ons-list-item class="assgn-list" ng-controller="itemNameCtrl"> 
        {{itemName}} 
        <input type='text' ng-model='itemName' />
      </ons-list-item>
     <ons-button modifier="large--quiet" onclick="myNavigator.popPage()">Back</ons-button>
  </ons-page>
</script>
```

An odd thing I noticed is, if the `<ons-button>` is removed from the template (dessert.html), the interpolation doesn't work. I can honestly say I am not sure why that is. I have developed `ons-page` without `ons-button` and never had this issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks, I reproduced the same code on my project and it works fine with the ons-button. Without it, it fails. I think I'll have to take a deeper look on what's happening with the scope and angular, when pages are pushed on the stack from the navigator.

Comment: Agreed. My interest in peaked and I'll report any findings here. Good luck